# What does "RAX" mean?

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology, starcraft-terran

I'm new to Starcraft and when I look on the Starcraft subreddit or here in some questions I often encounter term **RAX** usually in context with Terrans. But I don't know what it means.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"RAX" is shorthand for "barracks", a Terran structure that produces infantry units.

It's often used to describe build orders. So something like "3-Rax Reaper" is denoting an opener that involves getting three barracks quickly and producing Reaper units with them.

Comment: Ahhh...  I get it now... just read it out loud and it makes sense, Thanks.

Comment: No prob. Unfortunately, there's a lot of jargon in Starcraft to get used to.

Comment: Fortunately a lot of terms are here described.